# CodeIgniter Query Escaping Quotes

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following simple query which works perfectly in MySQL;

```
select * from client_contact
where date_format(client_next_contact_on, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2018-07-25'
```

I've then added this in my codeigniter query but the error I get is;

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2018-07-25'' at line 3
>
> SELECT * FROM (client_contact) WHERE
>   dateformat(client_next_contact_on, '%Y-%m-%d') '2018-07-25'

By the looks of the above, it's missing the **=** in the query.

Here's my query in codeigniter;

```
$today = new DateTime();
$today_formatted = $today->format('Y-m-d');
$this->db->where('dateformat(client_next_contact_on, \'%Y-%m-%d\')', $today_formatted);
$return = $this->db->get('client_contact')->row_array();
```

If you're wondering why I need to use date_format, it's because it's stored as a date time in my database for other purposes. For this purpose, I need a list of clients that I need to contact today, regardless of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include the equals in the where statement, and rename dateformat as it isn't a function in MySQL. Use [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
$this->db->where('DATE_FORMAT(client_next_contact_on, \'%Y-%m-%d\') =', $today_formatted);
```

Now, onto the guts of why code igniter chose not to include an equals sign, which (by the documentation, it should have). On [this line](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/20f21fdd01032f94023243db4639f0dd1c1dd85d/system/database/DB_driver.php#L1483) of the codeigniter source, it calls this function to determine if it contains an operator. Apparently because you put a space after the `,` it believed you included an operator, so a simple manual adjustment to add this in is fine.

```
protected function _has_operator($str)
{
    return (bool) preg_match('/(<|>|!|=|\sIS NULL|\sIS NOT NULL|\sEXISTS|\sBETWEEN|\sLIKE|\sIN\s*\(|\s)/i', trim($str));
}
```

You can see where the regex matched here: https://regex101.com/r/BTuZxj/1